# Jeito pythonico de definir setters e getters

Tags: python, propriedade, getters-setters

Pesquisando na internet, vejo que é altamente recomendável não utilizar Setter e Getters em classes Python. Porém, não consigo determinar uma forma de acessar valores privados sem utilizá-los. Existem diversas recomendações sobre usar propriedades, porém não consigo entender a vantagem. Pois, não vejo a possibilidade de determinar um método para todos os atributos - e ainda sim - teria de determinar um método para cada - ou eu não estou entendendo seu uso.

Exemplo:

```
class Pessoa(object):
    def __init__(self, nome, idade, salario)
        self.__nome = nome
        self.__idade = idade
        self.__salario = salario

    def nomeGet(self):
        return self.__nome

    def nomeSet(self, nome):
        self.__nome = nome

    def idadeGet(self):
        return self.__idade

    def idadeSet(self, idade):
        self.__idade = idade

    def salarioGet(self):
        return self.__salario

    def salarioSet(self, salario):
        self.__salario = salario
```

Sei que não é considerado uma boa prática no Python definir tantos métodos acessores, porém, como mencionei antes não tenho ideia de como evitar isto, a imagem que tenho utilizando propriedade seria assim da mesma forma, a diferença seria instanciar a property para cada atributo. Alguém poderia me explicar a melhor forma de trabalhar com mais de um atributo, ou porque seria melhor utilizar propriedades?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

Quando "toda a Internet" diz uma coisa e você não quer fazer o mesmo - quem você acha que está indo na contramão?

Em Python não há o costume de se usar getters e setters,  por que tem que se pensar de uma forma diferente. Quando você fala em "atributos privados" - eles são privados para "quem"?

A ideia do encapsulamento em OO é que pessoas usando sua classe e métodos púbico não precisem se *preocupar* com os estados privados, nem devam tentar mexer neles diretamente. Isso facilita que na hora de desenvolver a classe você não precise se preocupar com "e se alguém deixar esse atributo inconsistente" entre duas chamadas de métodos, e para quem está usando não precisa se preocupar com "se eu alterar esse valor, será que quebro alguma coisa no funcionamento do objeto"?

O objetivo de atributos privados NÃO É, por exemplo, evitar que alguém que use sua classe possa ler algum valor que você considera privado por questões de segurança para se proteger de algo como um "programador mal intencionado" que esteja fazendo uso de sua classe.

Como linguagens como Java e C++ são definidas, dá a impressão de que atributos e métodos privados possam oferecer segurança contra um programador mal intencionado que esteja usando sua classe. Essa segurança não é real - em ambas as linguagens é possível se acessar esses atributos privados - as vezes dando muitas voltas.

Em Python e outras linguagens dinâmicas, o uso de introspecção torna bem fácil achar e usar qualquer atributo marcado como privado (mesmo os prefixados com `__`)

Em suma: se alguém está escrevendo código que vai rodar no mesmo processo que sua classe com atributos privados - ele pode e deve poder acessar os dados. É diferente do caso de um programador em um sistema diferente do seu que vai acessar seus dados por uma API. Nesse caso, os atributos privados simplesmente não são expostos na API. Em Python, em vez de tentar forçar atributos privados inacessíveis, é costume dizer que a linguagem é usada por "adultos que consentem" .

Então, a prática é prefixar atributos e  métodos privados com um único `_` : dessa forma quem for *usar* a classe sabe que não precisa mexer com esses atributos.

Agora, Python tem um mecanismo **muito** poderoso para acesso a atributos, que chamamos de "descriptor protocol" - isso é o que é usado internamente pelo `property` para permitir criar métodos - ele vai muito além do que o property permite (basicamente você pode definir atributos numa classe que automaticamente tem getters e setters customizados - basta criar uma classe especial para esses atributos com os métodos  `__get__`, `__set__` ou `__del__` -  o property faz isso).

Dito isso,  o property é um facilitador para você, ao querer ler ou escrever um atributo, executar algum código customizado que pode transformar ou validar o dado daquele atributo, quando ele for acessado (por exemplo, leia o valor de um banco de dados, faça uma formatação, validar o tipo do atributo, etc...).

Usar o property (ou getters e setters) para simplesmente guardar o valor como ele veio e devolve-lo como veio, não faz sentido -  a não ser, por exemplo, que você queira que a classe seja thread-safe e use esse código para usar locks e semaphores na alteração dos atributos.  E é por "não fazer sentido" que a internet recomenda que não se faça - simplesmente por que o seu programa vai ser exatamente o **mesmo** com ou sem os getters e setters -

Sem o property:

```
class Teste:
    def __init__(self, valor):
        self.valor = valor
```

Com o property:

```
class Teste:
    def __init__(self, nome):
         self.nome = nome

    @property
    def nome(self):
         # Este código é executado quando alguém for
         # ler o valor de self.nome
         return self._nome

    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, value):
         # este código é executado sempre que alguém fizer 
         # self.nome = value
         self._nome = value
```

E pronto - quem vai usar seu código, não vai usar uma chamada ao "setter" - a mágica do Python é que se você precisar colocar lógica customizada no getter e no setter, isso é completamente transparente para quem *usa* sua classe e seus atributos.  Se nenhuma lógica extra é necessária para um dado atributo, não tem por que criar um property pra ele.

Comment: "...thread-safe e use esse código para usar locks e semaphores na alteração dos atributos.", muito bom exemplo de uma coisa muito util que se pode alcançar deste modo

Comment: Agora ficou bem mais claro, como é mais acessível em videos do youtube aulas de Orientação a Objetos em outras linguagens, como Java por exemplo, durante o aprendizado acabei ficando com alguns vícios e eu gosto do estilo de programação do Python bem mais que do java, portanto sempre que me deparo com situações onde no java seria feito de determinado jeito e a comunidade Python diz para evitar antes de aderir quero entender porque evitar (não menosprezando a comunidade é claro, com certeza são muito mais experientes que eu, é apenas questão de aprendizado). Muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Tem um artigo legal sobre esse e outros costumes para quem vem de linguagens estáticas. Ele é antigo, mas sempre foi um "clássico" - ó "Python n~ao é Java": http://dirtsimple.org/2004/12/python-is-not-java.html

Answer (score 14):

Existe exatamente [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters) no SO EN.

Se precisas mesmo de setters e getters, dever usá-los através de *[property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)*, ex:

```
class Pessoa(object):
    def __init__(self, nome, idade, salario):
        self._nome = nome
        self._idade = idade
        self._salario = salario

    @property
    def nome(self):
        print('get do nome')
        return self._nome

    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, nome):
        print('set do nome', nome)
        self._nome = nome

    @property
    def idade(self):
        print('get da idade')
        return self._idade

    @idade.setter
    def idade(self, idade):
        print('set da idade', idade)
        self._idade = idade

    @property
    def salario(self):
        print('get do salario')
        return self._salario

    @salario.setter
    def salario(self, salario):
        print('set do salario', salario)
        self._salario = salario


pessoa = Pessoa('Miguel', 30, 50)
print(pessoa.__dict__) # valores iniciais
pessoa.nome = 'Afonso'
pessoa.idade = 20
pessoa.salario = 500
print(pessoa.nome)
print(pessoa.idade)
print(pessoa.salario)
```

Isto é util se quiseres que algum código seja executado (como por ex, os *prints* em cima que estão dentro dos métodos) quando fazes *set, get, del* em alguma propriedade.

Olhando para [outras pesquisas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8297723/oop-getter-setter-methods/8297779#8297779) e artigos escritos por pessoas que sabem mais que eu, concordo plenamente.

> ...just access the attribute itself, or, if you need code to be run every time the attribute is accessed or set, use properties.

Que traduzido é:

> ...acede logo ao próprio atributo, ou, se precisares que algum código seja executado sempre que o atributo seja acedido/definido (*set/get*) usa *properties* (o meu exemplo em cima)

E aqui está um exemplo, tendo em conta o teu código, do que eu faria (caso não precisasse que nada extra fosse executado num *get/set/del*), tento manter o mais simples possível:

```
class Pessoa(object):
    def __init__(self, nome, idade, salario):
        self.nome = nome
        self.idade = idade
        self.salario = salario

pessoa = Pessoa('Miguel', 30, 50)
print(pessoa.__dict__) # valores iniciais
pessoa.nome = 'Afonso'
pessoa.idade = 20
pessoa.salario = 500
print(pessoa.__dict__) # novos valores
print(pessoa.nome)
print(pessoa.idade)
print(pessoa.salario)
```

Neste ultimo exemplo talvez adicionasse só os metodos para retorno, (def get_nome, ...) por uma questão de legibilidade, mas não é de todo necessário/convenção.

"Beleza da simplicidade de Python, não a desperdices"

Comment: Valeu cara, ainda estou meio confuso quando a vantagem de usar propriedades em vez de setters e getters, mas entendi o modo geral. Obrigado. (ainda tenho dúvida quanto acessar atributos privados.)

Answer (score -3):

```
class Pessoa(object):

    def __init__(self, nome, idade, salario):
        self.__nome = nome
        self.__idade = idade
        self.__salario = salario

    def nomeGet(self):
        return self.__nome

    def nomeSet(self, nome):
        self.__nome = nome

    def idadeGet(self):
        return self.__idade

    def idadeSet(self, idade):
        self.__idade = idade

    def salarioGet(self):
        return self.__salario

    def salarioSet(self, salario):
        self.__salario = salario
print(Pessoa)
```