# Erro: "Maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"

Tags: python

```
class Ponto(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self.x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, valor):
        self.x = valor
```

Quando eu executo o script gera:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
>    x = Ponto(2)
>  File "C:/Users/ThiagoDEV/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/OOP39.py", line 3, in __init__
>    self.x = x
>  File "C:/Users/ThiagoDEV/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/OOP39.py", line 9, in x
>    self.x = valor
>  File "C:/Users/ThiagoDEV/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/OOP39.py", line 9, in x
>    self.x = valor
>  File "C:/Users/ThiagoDEV/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/OOP39.py", line 9, in x
>    self.x = valor
>  [Previous line repeated 491 more times]
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
> ```

Comment: Não a identação está correta é que na horas de postar não deu tabulação

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro é devido a estares a *settar* uma propriedade que tem o mesmo nome do teu `setter`, e do seu método:

```
@x.setter
def x(self, valor):
    self.x = valor # valor de x muda aqui
```

Sempre que este valor muda volta a chamar o setter, que tem o mesmo nome da propriedade (e do método), e entra em recursividade.

Para evitar isso, convencionalmente coloca-se `_` antes de uma nova propriedade com mesmo nome:

```
class Ponto(object):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x
    @x.setter
    def x(self, valor):
        self._x = valor
        print('x mudou para', self.x) # self.x também muda

p = Ponto(32)
p.x = 10
p.x = 15
print(p.x)
```

[DEMONSTRAÇÃO](https://repl.it/Mooi/1)

Nota que podes também no `__init__` fazer `self._x = x` em vez do que temos. Desta forma, na criação do objeto (`p = Ponto(32)`), `self._x = x` não é assumido pelo `setter`.

[Leitura complementar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186982/jeito-pythonico-de-definir-setters-e-getters/186985#186985)