# O melhor jeito para usar getters e setters

Tags: python-3.x, getters-setters

Comecei a estudar programação faz pouco tempo e a linguagem escolhida foi Python. E estou encontrando muita dificuldade para enter o uso de `getters`, `setters` e propriedades.

Nas minhas navegações pela internet, descobri que o uso de `property` é mais recomendável que o uso de `getters` e `setters` no Python, mas também não entendi seus conceitos.

Será que alguém poderia me ajudar a entender o motivo do uso desses métodos e o melhor jeito de como usa-los?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Jeito pythonico de definir setters e getters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186982/jeito-pythonico-de-definir-setters-e-getters)

Comment: Já tem uma excelente resposta aqui também: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627002/whats-the-pythonic-way-to-use-getters-and-setters