# Erro "maximum recursion depth exceeded" ao implementar setter

Tags: python, classes

Estou aprendendo python e escrevi o seguinte código:

```
class Produto:

    def __init__(self, nome, preco):
        self.nome = nome
        self.preco = preco

    def desconto(self, percentual):
        self.preco = self.preco - self.preco * percentual / 100

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self.nome

    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, valor):
        self.nome = valor

    @property 
    def preco(self):
        return self.preco

    @preco.setter
    def preco(self, valor):
        self.preco = valor

p1 = Produto('Camiseta', 50)

p1.desconto(10)
```

Porém, ao executar, é exibido o seguinte erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\levil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\teste.py", line 27, in <module>
    p1 = Produto('Camiseta', 50)
  File "C:\Users\levil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\teste.py", line 4, in __init__
    self.nome = nome
  File "C:\Users\levil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\teste.py", line 16, in nome
    self.nome = valor
  File "C:\Users\levil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\teste.py", line 16, in nome
    self.nome = valor
  File "C:\Users\levil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\teste.py", line 16, in nome
    self.nome = valor
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Alguém poderia me explicar do que se trata?

Comment: considere 1) editar o título para refletir melhor o conteúdo da pergunta e 2) aceitar uma das respostas caso elas tenha respondido sua dúvida.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondendo a sua pergunta a mensagem de erro informa que um dos atributos de sua classe `Produto` está em loop se auto atualizando recursivamente.

Dando uma atenção a mensagem de erro:

> File "C:\Users\levil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\teste.py", line
> 27, in 
> `p1 = Produto('Camiseta', 50)`

- Informa que o criar de uma instancia da classe `Produto` desencadeou uma exceção...

> File "C:\Users\levil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\teste.py", line
> 4, in **init**
> `self.nome = nome`

- Informa que dento do constructor ao realizar a atividade de atribuir o argumento `nome` para o atributo `Produto.nome` foi desencadeado uma exceção...

> File "C:\Users\levil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\teste.py", line
> 16, in nome
> `self.nome = valor`

- Informa que dentro da função destinada a armazenar o `valor` para o atributo `Produto.nome` foi realizada uma tentativa de atribuição ao argumento `valor` para o atributo `Produto.nome`...

> File "C:\Users\levil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\teste.py", line
> 16, in nome
> `self.nome = valor`
> File "C:\Users\levil\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\teste.py", line 16, in
> nome
> `self.nome = valor`
> [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
>
> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

- Que por sua vez informa que novamente chamou a função destinada a armazenar o `valor` para o atributo `Produto.nome` onde foi realizada uma tentativa de atribuição ao argumento `valor` para o atributo `Produto.nome` e novamente chamou a função destinada a armazenar o `valor` para o atributo `Produto.nome` onde foi realizada uma tentativa de atribuição ao argumento `valor` para o atributo `Produto.nome` e novamente chamou a função destinada a armazenar o `valor` para o atributo `Produto.nome` onde foi realizada uma tentativa de atribuição ao argumento `valor` para o atributo `Produto.nome` e novamente chamou a função destinada a armazenar o `valor` para o atributo `Produto.nome` onde foi realizada uma tentativa de atribuição ao argumento `valor` para a propriedade `Produto.nome`....
  ...isso por 994 vezes até que [a profundidade máxima de recursão](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getrecursionlimit) foi violada desencadeando uma exceção [RecursionError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RecursionError).

Depois de analisar a mensagem de erro e reanalisar o código é possível concluir que mesmo ocorrerá com o atributo `Produto.preco` após corrigir o problema com `Produto.nome`.

Para *reparar* o código e o *fazer funcionar* é fazer com que as funções que atribuem valores aos atributos `Produto.nome` e `Produto.preco` não mais invoquem a si mesmos e que armazenem seus respectivos valores em variáveis da instancia como você instituiu [métodos acessores e modificadores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutator_method) para atributos é presumível que essas variáveis da instancia sejam [variáveis privadas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_modifiers).

```
class Produto:

    def __init__(self, nome, preco):
        #Atribui os argumentos aos seus respectivos atributos.
        self.nome = nome              
        self.preco = preco          

    def desconto(self, percentual):
        self.preco = self.preco - self.preco * percentual / 100

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self._nome            #Retorna o valor da variável privada _nome

    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, valor):
        self._nome = valor           #Atribui valor a variável privada _nome

    @property 
    def preco(self):
        return self._preco           #Retorna o valor da variável privada _preco

    @preco.setter
    def preco(self, valor):
        self._preco = valor           #Atribui valor a variável privada _preco

p1 = Produto('Camiseta', 50)

p1.desconto(10)

print(p1.preco)                       #imprime 45.0
```

Como fazer funcionar não é o mesmo que estar correto, os seus dois atributos `Produto.nome` e `Produto.preco` são prolixos pois da forma implementada são apenas variáveis públicas dotadas dum overhead intrínseco, a implementação de métodos acessores e modificadores que fazem o mesmo que uma variável pública faria. Talvez o método `Produto.desconto()` seja um candidato a se tornar um atributo pois pode ser interessante saber o percentual de desconto incidente num `Produto` e quando redefinido o desconto automaticamente modificaria o preço:

```
class Produto:

    def __init__(self, nome, preco, desconto=0):
        #Atribui os argumentos a suas respectivas variáveis públicas.
        self.nome = nome                 
        self.preco = preco
        self.desconto = desconto                    

    #Acessor do atributo desconto.
    @property
    def desconto(self):
        return self._desconto             #Retorna o valor da variável privada _desconto.
        
    #Modificador do atributo desconto.
    @desconto.setter
    def desconto(self, percentual): 
        self._desconto = percentual                              #Atribui percentual a variável privada _desconto
        self.preco = self.preco - self.preco * percentual / 100  #Recalcula o preço com o novo percentual
        

    
p1 = Produto('Camiseta', 50)

p1.desconto = 10                 

print(p1.preco)                   #imprime 45.0
```

Outra possível abordagem é ter `Produto.nome` e `Produto.desconto` como variáveis públicas e `Produto.preco` com um atributo somente leitura:

```
class Produto:

    def __init__(self, nome, preco, desconto=0):
        #Atribui os argumentos a suas respectivas variáveis públicas .
        self.nome = nome   
        self.desconto = desconto   
        #Atribui os argumentos a suas respectivas variáveis privadas.
        self._preco = preco                 

    #Define o atributo readonly com valor calculado na consulta
    @property
    def preco(self):
        return self._preco - self._preco * self.desconto / 100

    
    
p1 = Produto('Camiseta', 50)

p1.desconto = 10                 

print(p1.preco)                   #imprime 45.0
```

Somente analisando os requisitos do projeto que pode-se decidir qual a melhor forma de implementar a classe `Produto`. Pois por exemplo pode ter um requisito onde especifica que uma vez criado o produto o seu nome não pode ser alterado, ou então um requisito implicando que quando alterar o nome do produto automaticamente um banco de dados seja atualizado.

Comment: Aaah, entendi, muito obrigado pelo seu tempo ;)

Answer (score 3):

Seu código está entrando em loop, isso porque a sua propriedade interna `nome` também é um `setter`.

Então quando você faz faz uma atribuição em `self.nome`, como é feito no construtor da classe, ele chama o `@nome.setter`, que por sua vez faz novamente uma atribuição em `nome` e chamada novamente o `@nome.setter` entrando em um loop infinito, até gerar exceção.

Para entender melhor, rode o exemplo no link abaixo, ele tem alguns prints para você visualizar melhor a situação:

https://repl.it/@Dadinel/ScornfulWarlikeInterpreter

---

Para corrigir a situação, é comum tratarmos as propriedades internas da classe Python começando com underline, exemplo:

```
class Produto:

    def __init__(self, nome, preco):
        self.nome = nome
        self.preco = preco

    def desconto(self, percentual):
        self.preco = self.preco - self.preco * percentual / 100

    @property
    def nome(self):
        return self._nome

    @nome.setter
    def nome(self, valor):
        self._nome = valor

    @property 
    def preco(self):
        return self._preco

    @preco.setter
    def preco(self, valor):
        self._preco = valor

p1 = Produto('Camiseta', 50)

print(p1.preco)

p1.desconto(10)

print(p1.nome)
print(p1.preco)
```

> Veja online: https://repl.it/@Dadinel/UnawareGiddyDriver

---

Dê uma olhada nessa pergunta e resposta sobre getters e setters em Python:

[Jeito pythonico de definir setters e getters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186982/jeito-pythonico-de-definir-setters-e-getters)

Comment: Entendii, muito obrigado pelo seu tempo... Vou ver o link ;)