# Todo atributo precisa de métodos assessores?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orientação-a-objetos

Estou aprendendo POO em Python e fiquei em dúvida se devo usar os métodos assessores para todos os atributos que eu incluir em uma classe. Por exemplo, seu eu criar uma classe com 20 atributos, nos quais serão lidos e escritos valores, eu deveria, por convenção, criar 40 métodos assessores (20 Getters + 20 Setters)?

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Jeito pythonico de definir setters e getters](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186982/jeito-pythonico-de-definir-setters-e-getters), Dê ênfase a esse trecho *Usar o property (ou getters e setters) para simplesmente guardar o valor como ele veio e devolve-lo como veio, não faz sentido*

Comment: Adicionei mais 2 perguntas no box azul acima, leia para ver que o assunto vai **muito** além do que as respostas abaixo dizem (aliás, nenhuma deveria ter sido aceita, de tão simplistas que são - lembre-se que a ideia do site é ter respostas completas que sirvam tb para visitantes futuros - basta ver as respostas dos links indicados acima, aquilo sim é o que esperamos - ou pelo menos, o que deveríamos buscar). Apesar de não serem em Python, os 2 links que adicionei dão uma visão mais geral (embora no Python haja particularidades explicadas no primeiro link - sobre o "Jeito pythônico")

Comment: Complementando, [ver aqui também](/q/88546/112052), para entender que Orientação a Objeto é bem mais complicado do que parece (além dos links já indicados, pode ver mais [aqui](/questions/tagged/encapsulamento?tab=Votes)). Por fim, outro problema de aceitar a resposta abaixo é que ela desconsidera o contexto específico do Python (onde nada é realmente privado), e ainda propaga isso pela internet, ajudando a disseminar desinformação (e tem outra sutileza sobre o uso do termo atributo, [ver aqui](/q/269089/112052))

Comment: Aliás, se tiver 20 atributos na classe talvez você não esteja delegando as responsabilidades corretamente (e isso é outro ponto bem importante fora desse tópico).

Answer (score -3):

Em POO um dos pilares é  o encapsulamento dos atributos e portanto,  acredito que sim.

Sou novato tbm, mas lembrando que os métodos  gets e setters referem-se respectivamente ao acesso e modificação  dos atributos de uma determinasa classe uma vez que colocados em privado(encapsulados).

Portanto, se vc pretende acessa-los quando  criar instancias desse objeto, há  necessidade sim de criar metodos acessores e modificadores.